# Kafka Connect MaskField SMT fails on tombstones

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I want to apply the MaskField SMT on a field in a specific topic. The MaskField SMT fails with `Only Map objects supported in absence of schema for [mask fields], found: null` when encountering tombstone events (null value). To apply masking only on the selected topic, I'm using the `TopicNameMatches` predicate, but I don't find a way to apply a negated `RecordIsTombstone` *as well*. I found that for some SMTs there is an option to let tombstone through without being affected by the transformation, but can't seem to do anything about it for MaskField. Is there a way to achieve this without writing a custom SMT (using Kafka Connect 6.0.1)?

My config currently:

```
transforms: mask_trf
transforms.mask_trf.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value
transforms.mask_trf.fields: foo
transforms.mask_trf.replacement: ***
transforms.mask_trf.predicate: pred
predicates: pred
predicates.pred.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches
predicates.pred.pattern: t1
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom SMT that extends MaskField. The only change is that in apply() it checks if it's a tombstone, and if so, returns the record unchanged. Otherwise it calls MaskField's apply.